# How can l make my React slider component infinite in the x axis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, infinite-carousel

I've never built a React slider before and I'm struggling a bit with making it an infinite loop of slides. Currently there are two slides, but I'd like to make it so that the user can click the next/previous buttons and the slides are infinite, repeating slide 1 and slide 2, over and over.

I have built a container for the slide content called `Testimonial`. The width of the container is 800px.

The slider has `next` and `prev` buttons to have the slider move left and right.

Slider.tsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { SliderTypes } from '../../@types/types';
import Testimonial from '../components/Testimonial';

const Slider = (props: SliderTypes) => {

  const sliderData = [
    {
      index: 0,
      image: 'image',
      header: 'Header text',
      testimonial: 'Testimonial description',
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      image: 'image',
      header: 'Header text',
      testimonial: 'Testimonial description',
    },
  ];

  const [properties, setProperties] = useState(sliderData);
  const [property, setProperty] = useState(sliderData[0]);

  const nextProperty = () => {
    const newIndex = property.index + 1;
    setProperty(properties[newIndex]);
  };

  const prevProperty = () => {
    const newIndex = property.index - 1;
    setProperty(properties[newIndex]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => nextProperty()}
        disabled={property.index === properties.length - 1}
      >
        Next
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => prevProperty()} disabled={property.index === 0}>
        Prev
      </button>

      <CardSlider className={`card-slider active-slide-${property.index}`}>
        <CardSliderWrapper
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(-${
              property.index * (200 / properties.length)
            }%)`,
          }}
        >
          {sliderData.map(({ index, image, header, testimonial }) => (
            <Testimonial
              key={index}
              images={image}
              header={header}
              testimonial={testimonial}
            />
          ))}
        </CardSliderWrapper>
      </CardSlider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

I appreciate any insights. Thanks in advance!